# Flowlayout Panel Disable Middle Mouse Wheel Scrolling

Tags: c#

I want to prevent the `Middle Mouse Wheel` from scrolling my `FlowlayoutPanel`

What i tried but doesn't (idk why)

```
flowLayoutPanel.MouseWheel += (sender, args) => 
    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)args).Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to inherit the control yourself and comment out the base call:

```
public class FlowPanel : FlowLayoutPanel {
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e) {
    // base.OnMouseWheel(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Lol i like simplicity :D